# WMP: unable to control/handle events when in fullscreen

Tags: c#, .net, windows-media-player, wmp

I have added a Windows Media control to my form and have been able to use it perfectly except when it is in the fullscreen state. It seems that I am unable to manipulate any aspects of the control through key events within my application. My current goal is to handle 'esc' key down to exit out of full screen. I can do more from there on.

If you have any idea please let me know!

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once found this code somewhere and worked pretty well, but don't remember where i got it from.

```
    public partial class WMForm : Form,IMessageFilter

{

    public WMForm()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void WMForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        this.MyWindowsMediaPlayer.URL = @"YourFilePath/Url";

        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);

    }



    private void WMForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)

    {

        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);

    }



    #region IMessageFilter

    private const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)

    {

        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)

        {

            Keys keyCode = (Keys)(int)m.WParam & Keys.KeyCode;

            if (keyCode == Keys.Escape)

            {

                this.MyWindowsMediaPlayer.fullScreen = false;

            }

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back to you. The 50 bounty will be yours if it works!

Comment: Well I got around to trying it today. Thanks tons, what a great way to implement keydowns for my WMP project.
Thanks!